# Jenkins, Python and root

Tags: python, jenkins

I am trying to run Python unittest as part of a Jenkins build.  My build was failing as follows:

```
+ export PYTHONPATH=/usr/lib/python2.7:/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/GUPS_Unit_Tests/workspace/python/plugins:/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/GUPS_Unit_Tests/workspace/:/usr/share/qgis/python:/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins:/var/lib/jenkins/.qgis2/python/plugins:/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/GUPS_Unit_Tests/workspace/gupsutest
+ export PYTHONHOME=/usr
+ cd gupsutest
+ python -m unittest discover
ImportError: No module named site
```

As it turns out this is a file permission issue.  Python is installed at /usr/lib/python2.7, which of course is owned by root.

```
-rwxrwxr--   1 root root  20388 Jun 22  2015 site.py
-rwxrwxr--   1 root root  19727 Feb  2 07:45 site.pyc
```

I can get Python to run if I add the jenkins user to the root group.  This seems dangerous at worst and bad form at best.

How can I proceed?  Do I reinstall Python to /usr/local/lib?  Do I change the group for Python in /usr/lib?  Do I allow all access to /usr/lib/python2.7?

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 with Python 2.7.6.  Something else to consider, the Python code we are writing is for QGIS plugins.  These have also been installed as root.  Should I change the group for these as well?

EDIT: More info.  The jenkins user is set up as a system user account.  That seems to be contributing to the issue.  I have a normal account gups which is able to run Python (and thus has access to /usr/lib/python2.7).

/etc/group

```
jenkins:x:125:
gups:x:1000:
```

/etc/passwd

```
jenkins:x:116:125:Jenkins,,,:/var/lib/jenkins:/bin/bash
gups:x:1000:1000:GUPS Buildmaster,,,:/home/gups:/bin/bash
```

EDIT2: Interesting difference between python folder permissions.  Not sure why python3.4 and python2.7 are different.

```
gups@gups-xxxxxxxxxx:~$ ls -la /usr/lib | grep python
-rw-r--r--   1 root root        68232 Jan 16 20:42 libqgispython.so.2.8.6
drwxrwxr--  26 root root        12288 Feb 12 08:03 python2.7
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root         4096 Feb 23  2014 python3
drwxr-xr-x  33 root root        20480 Feb  4 05:16 python3.4
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root         4096 Feb  3 08:02 python-tz
```

EDIT3:
I've been looking into [virtualenv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) which seems like an appropriate solution.  I ran virtualenv to create an environment in my jeknins user's home directory.

```
sudo virtualenv --system-site-packages /var/lib/jenkins/_python
```

This does not include /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages, which is a problem.

EDIT4:
Jenkins package info.

```
gups@gups-Satellite-U925t:~$ sudo dpkg -l | grep jenkins
ii  jenkins                                               1.650                                               all          continuous integration system
```

Comment: Those permissions look wacky. What `umask` was used during the install?

Comment: Default.  I think this Python was installed as part of the Ubuntu installation.  umask is giving me 0002.  I have not changed it.

Comment: Did you do any local installations at any point? Debian (and therefore Ubuntu) is nothing is not consistent. If `/usr/lib/python 2.7` has different permissions from the other python installations, that clearly points to something being wrong. I just checked my own installation, and all the python versions (in my case, `python2.6`, `python2.7`, `python3`, `python3.4`) all have the same permissions. `umask` gives me 0022 here. I think that's standard. Can you do something like `dpkg -l | grep python`. Don't post it necessarily, just see if it tells you anything.

Comment: Also, can you say which jenkins packages you have installed?

Comment: I have not done any local installations of Python.  dpkg shows me quite a bit, not sure what I'm looking for.  Apologies, I'm pretty new with Python, Linux admin and etc.  Jenkins packages?  Plugins?  It's a fairly stock install.  I'm just trying to get a build to run a simple Python script at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some additional searching and some help from a post in the [Ubuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2315792), I have discovered the solution.

As indicated by [thrig](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/128228/thrig) and [Faheem Mitha](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/4671/faheem-mitha), the permissions on my python2.7 folder were in fact funky.

I fixed them as so.

```
sudo chmod 755 /usr/lib/python2.7
sudo find /usr/lib/python2.7 -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
sudo find /usr/lib/python2.7/*.py -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

Which I found in [this stackexchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740152/how-to-set-chmod-for-a-folder-and-all-of-its-subfolders-and-files-in-linux-ubunt) post.